# Getting Google YouTube API Service Account Access Token in PHP

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to obtain an access token from Google so I can use a 'service account' to upload videos to YouTube automatically.

This code:

```
$credentials = array(
        'client_id' => $my_client_id
    );

$jwt = JWT::encode($credentials, $private_key);

$client = new Google_Client();

if ($client->authenticate($jwt))
{
   // do something
}
```

Fails with this exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request: Client must specify either client_id or client_assertion, not both'' in /home/google/client/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:120
```

Where am I going wrong?

TY!

Answer (score 1):

I had missed a large section of the documentation as shown here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt

I had also missed that the algorithm *had* to be RSA256 not HSA256 as defaulted to in the JWT PHP encode function.

And further, that I needed to POST a request, appropriately, directly to get an access token to endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

The Google private JSON private key for the service account also was invalid for use by openssl due to the final character being encoded/included as:

\u003d

Swapping this, literally, with:

=

solved that problem.

Here is my now working (ish, see closing statement) code:

```
$claimset = array(
        'iss'          => $client_email,
        'scope'        => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
        'aud'          => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
        'exp'          => time() + 1800,
        'iat'          => time(),
        'sub'          => 'my google account email@gmail.com'); // not sure if reqd

$jwt = JWT::encode($claimset, $private_key, 'RS256');

// Now need to get a token by posting the above to:
// https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

# Our new data
$data = array(
      'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion'  => $jwt
    );

# Create a connection
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token';
$ch = curl_init($url);

# Form data string
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

# Setting our options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

# Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print "and here is what we got: ";
print_r($response);
exit;
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the response I'm getting is:

{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }

Suspect my service account does not yet have the right to upload to YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an experr, but you should probably look at removing the "," at the end of you line here:

```
'client_id'    => $private_key['client_id'],
//'client_email' => $private_ket['client_email']
```

change to:

```
'client_id'    => $private_key['client_id']
//'client_email' => $private_ket['client_email']
```

I've used this example to get oauth working. It may be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632721.aspx

you could also try oauth testing here:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Good luck!